# How can I assign a Wordpress blog in network site to a subdirectory of a domain that is not the primary domain

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently running a Wordpress network website with 30 + domains which are all different like example.ta, example.es and example.com(primary domain) etc. Now I want to add one more site but map it to example.ta/de for example. But when I add the site to the network it always redirects to example.ta and ignores the installation on example.ta/de/.

The website example.ta/de/ is a clone of a different domain in the network. I did a search and replace in the database for this site but with no luck. When I assign the site to the primary domain of the website it does show the website (example.com/de/). Do I need to change something in the DNS or .htacces to make this work?

In the same network there are some websites that work with a subdirectory like example.be/fr/, but these installation where added before my time, and before domain mapping became a native function in Wordpress 4.5. I did not find any trace of special rules for these domain in the code or .htaccess.

Answer (score -1):

What is your web hosting control panel? For instance, if you're hosted on cPanel, you can add your domains and de-select the share document option for using the example.ta/de in a directory other than the main domain's directory.

Am I understood correctly?